# ADX: Update policy cross database

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, adx

Is it possible to create an update policy across databases?
I mean like table_1 in db_1 should send data via update policy to table_2 in db_2.

If not, why does it not work?

And: What about functions? Can i select data across dbs?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to create update policy across databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is it possible to create an update policy across databases*?

as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy), this is not currently supported:

*The policy-related query can invoke stored functions, but can't access data external to the database.*
*specifically:*

- *It can't perform cross-database queries*
- *It can't perform cross-cluster queries*
  *...*

> *If not, why does it not work?*

this is currently blocked due to security considerations. it may be supported in the future using managed identities.

> *What about functions? Can i select data across dbs?*

stored functions are allowed to include cross-database references.

for example:

```
.create function MyFunction() {
    database("MyOtherDatabase").MyTable
    | summarize max(Timestamp)
}
```